# GET Request is waiting before sent in firefox

Tags: http, firefox, express, get

I'm working on a Node/Express webApp which take a lot of dependency client side.
I was analyzing all the packet in the Network tab in firefox devtool and I saw something strange for me...

[image: request]

Why is firefox waiting every 6 request to send 6 new ?
All of theses request is pointing to the same server.

Can I do something to this ?
Like make all of them at the same time or it's out of my power ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the default number for maximum connections per host for Firefox (and Chrome for that matter) is 6.

For Firefox, this value can be changed by navigating to `about:config` and then changing the value for `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server`.

Comment: Okay so i can't do something to this from the webApp.. alright !

Whys is the number so low ?

Thanks